# Print an IloNumArray to a file inside an Incumbent Callback (C++)

Tags: c++, cplex

I'm trying to print an `IloNumArray` to a file using `fprintf()`. The problem is that I don't know the length of the Array since it's filled by a `getValues()` method inside an Incumbent Callback.

The code of the Callback where I'm having the problem is the following one:

```
ILOINCUMBENTCALLBACK3(MyFirstcallback,
                  IloCplex, cplex,
                  IloInt, contador,
                  IloNumVarArray, varenteras){
int i;
int length=0;
IloNum CurrentInc = MAX_COL;
IloNum BestTime = 0;
IloNum BestObj = MAX_COL;
IloNumArray BestSol(varenteras.getEnv());

IloNum FirstTime = 0;
IloNum FirstObj = MAX_COL;
IloNumArray FirstSol(varenteras.getEnv());


if ( hasIncumbent() ) {

    if (contador == 0 || contador == 1){
        contador+=1;
        FirstObj=getIncumbentObjValue();
        getValues(FirstSol,varenteras);
        FirstTime=cplex.getTime();


        length=sizeof(FirstSol)/sizeof(FirstSol[0]);   
//The first issue is here, length should be the size of the solution, and it's not giving it.


        printf("El tiempo %lf el valor %lf el largo de la solucion %d \n",FirstTime,FirstObj,length);           
        FILE* out;
        out = fopen("ResultadoPruebaTamanotest.txt","at+");
        fprintf(out,"%lf \t %lf \n",FirstTime,FirstObj);
        for (i=0;i<length;i++){
            fprintf(out,"%d \t",FirstSol[i]);
        }
        fprintf(out,"\n");
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

IloNumArray has a getSize() member that should tell you how many elements are in it.